# How to do summarise_all with values filter irrespective to the column

Tags: r, dplyr

I have 5 columns in which I'd like to group by a column and then summarize as mean per columns. However, in the process, I'd like to only calculate the mean for values between a certain range for all the columns. Is this possible? Not excluding the rows themselves but the values to be aggregated.

Current code:

```
a <- b %>% group_by(c) %>% summarise_all(funs(mean(., na.rm=T)))
```

Comment: More explanation would help. "I'd like to only calculate the mean for values between a certain range for all the columns" -- does that mean, for instance, that anything under 10 and over 90 should be ignored, or included but capped at that extreme? If you could give an example of input data and desired output that would help make it clear what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use only a subset of data to compute the mean on, you can use a lambda function inside `summarise()`.

However, if the subset is based on only one variable, you should simply use `filter()`.

Also, note that `summarise_all()` is retired and we should use `summarise(across())` instead.

Here is an example where the mean is computed with only values included between `2` and `3`.

```r
library(tidyverse)
iris %>% 
  group_by(Species) %>% 
  summarise(across(everything(), ~mean(.x, na.rm=TRUE)))
#> # A tibble: 3 x 5
#>   Species    Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width
#>   <fct>             <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl>
#> 1 setosa             5.01        3.43         1.46       0.246
#> 2 versicolor         5.94        2.77         4.26       1.33 
#> 3 virginica          6.59        2.97         5.55       2.03

my_range = c(inf=2, sup=3)
iris %>% 
  group_by(Species) %>% 
  summarise(across(everything(), ~.x[.x>my_range["inf"] & .x<my_range["sup"]] %>% mean(na.rm=TRUE)))
#> # A tibble: 3 x 5
#>   Species    Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width
#>   <fct>             <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl>
#> 1 setosa              NaN        2.60          NaN      NaN   
#> 2 versicolor          NaN        2.63          NaN      NaN   
#> 3 virginica           NaN        2.69          NaN        2.27
```

<sup>Created on 2021-05-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>